# Проблемы с заголовочным файлом

Tags: c++

Есть у меня заголовочный файл Vector.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
class Vector
{
    double* _V;
    int _Size;
    void copy(const Vector&);
    void destroy();
public:
    Vector(const Vector&);
    Vector(int Size);
    ~Vector();
    Vector& operator = (const Vector&);
    double operator[](int index) const;
    double& operator[](int index);
    int size() const{
        return _Size;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Vector&);
    double drand();

    /* data */
};
#endif//VECTOR_H
```

И связанный с ним Vector.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "GMRES.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Vector.h"

void copy(const Vector& v){
        _Size = v.size();
        _V = new double[*Size];
        for (int i = 0; i < _Size; ++i){
            *V[i] = v[i];
        }
    }
    void destroy(){
        delete[] _V;
    }
    Vector(const Vector& v){
        copy(v);
    }
    Vector(int size):_V(0),_Size(size) {
        _V = new double[_Size];
        for (int i = 0; i < _Size; ++i){
            _V[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~Vector(){
        destroy();
    }
    Vector& operator = (const Vector& v){
        if (this != &v)
        {
            destroy();
            copy(v);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    double operator[](int index) const{
        return _V[index];
    }
    double& operator[](int index){
        return _V[index];
    }   
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os,const Vector&){
        os << _V[i] << "\t";
    }
    double drand(){
        return std::rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    } 
    Vector randomVector(int size, double M)
    {
        Vector v(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {        
                v[i] = drand() * M;         
        }
        return v;
    }
```

И собственно этот срр никак не хочет дружить,говорит что Vector& - перегруженная ф-ия, которая не является именем типа.

Comment: @Radgalf покажите код этих файлов целиком - либо в вашем примере многое пропущено, либо вы насажали изрядное количество ошибок

Comment: Добавил весь код исполняемого.

Comment: @Radgalf у вас в коде уйма то ли ошибок, то ли опечаток, причем совсем не тех, о которых вы говорите. Скажем, все функции из **Vector.cpp** по логике должны являться реализациями функций, объявленных в **Vector.h**, но в вашем коде они  почему-то описаны как не относящиеся к классу. Или например в функции **copy** вы обращаетесь к переменной **Size**, которая нигде (во всяком случае в приведенном вами коде) не объявлена. И таких ошибок очень много

Comment: Угу, спасибо большое! Раз этот код такой кривой, то и смысла я так понимаю править его нет(а там еще 3 срр и 2.h).